# Outbound link tracking using Google Analytics in Adobe CQ5

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, aem, click-tracking

My client is currently using Adobe CQ5.

Each time I add the Google Analytics event tracking via CQ5, the code breaks.  (It doesn't matter whether I choose HTML view or design view.)

The code:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CC tracking test', 'CC CAN button click', 'Clicked',, false]);">Find a local cc branch</a>
```

Just wondering if there are other options for how this code can be implemented in CQ5.

Comment: Just to rule out the possibility of a typo, it would be useful for you to show the complete `<a>` tag that you have coded.

Comment: What's up with the double commas between 'Clicked' and false? Is that valid JS?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it into the page component for your pages, in the footer piece?  That way it will be on all of the pages, and it should work just fine there.  That's how I've done it on past projects in CQ5.